# Dirty check in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

As is known, Hibernate uses dirty check - that is, in DB it changes only fields that have changed in the entity of the program. How to know which fields have changed? Can I get old values?

Comment: No, it doesn't do that. Not by default at least. And no, it doesn't expose the old state of the entities. If you need to do that, you'll need to do it by yourself.

Comment: @JBNizet Old state is available through event listeners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a series of event listener SPIs in `org.hibernate.event.spi` that you can implement and register during the construction of a `SessionFactory` where you can obtain the state information your asking about.  For example:

```
public class MyPreUpdateEventListener implements PreUpdateEventListener {
  @Override
  public boolean onPreUpdate(PreUpdateEvent event) {
    Object[] newState = event.getState();
    Object[] oldState = event.getOldState();
    /* from this point, you'd need to determine the differences yourself */
  }
}
```